# Sqoop parallelism on cluster mode?

Tags: sqoop, bandwidth, mapper

Can anyone help me understand this stuff? I quite understand that when I run a Sqoop script the default mappers would be 4 and it runs parallel. So Sqoop is creating 4 sets of SQL script base on the primary key resulting in four chunks of data.

The thing I don't understand is whether these mappers run on all nodes? Because if each mapper runs on each node then the download would be much faster given that all of the node bandwidth is usable.

Or, alternatively, do all 4 of the mappers stay on the same node so that the parallelism effect would only be on the CPU (hyperthreading stuff) rather than the bandwidth and thus would only improve the download speed (a little) if each mapper doesn't consume the maximum bandwidth.

I'm really confused. Any input is appreciated. Nobody else has asked this question from what I can tell.